# matching relevant button to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, shuffle

I have created a favorites page that allows the user to save any item they choice. Every time this page loads/refreshes the items and buttons are randomized. Is there a way to match the items with the relevant button once shuffled/randomized? Below is a link to a quick example I made. Remove the comments from the JS to 'shuffle' the image and buttons.

https://jsfiddle.net/gu7ccv5d/2/

```js
/* var gridOnHomePage = document.querySelector(".grid"), // get the list
    temp = gridOnHomePage.cloneNode(true), // clone the list
    i = temp.children.length + 1;

// shuffle the cloned list (better performance)
while( i-- > 0 )
    temp.appendChild( temp.children[Math.random() * i |0] );

gridOnHomePage.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, gridOnHomePage); */
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Red_flag.svg/2000px-Red_flag.svg.png" width="50" height="50" />
  <button type="button" class="addToFavorites" color="red" img="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Red_flag.svg/2000px-Red_flag.svg.png">
    Add Red
  </button>
  <img src="http://epochmod.com/forum/uploads/monthly_2015_09/2000px-Solid_blue.svg.png.09e2d6f1de3f9a9192388a1737c19280.png" width="50" height="50" />
  <button type="button" class="addToFavorites" color="blue" img="http://epochmod.com/forum/uploads/monthly_2015_09/2000px-Solid_blue.svg.png.09e2d6f1de3f9a9192388a1737c19280.png">
    Add Blue
  </button>
  <img src="http://greensportsalliance.org/images/darkGreenSquare.gif" width="50" height="50" />
  <button type="button" class="addToFavorites" color="green" img="http://greensportsalliance.org/images/darkGreenSquare.gif">
    Add Green
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**here is a working snippet**

```js
var gridOnHomePage = document.querySelector(".grid"), // get the list
    temp = gridOnHomePage.cloneNode(true), // clone the list
    i = temp.children.length + 1;

// shuffle the cloned list (better performance)
while( i-- > 0 )
    temp.appendChild( temp.children[Math.random() * i |0] );

gridOnHomePage.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, gridOnHomePage);
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<span>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Red_flag.svg/2000px-Red_flag.svg.png" width="50" height="50" />
  <button type="button" class="addToFavorites" color="red" img="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Red_flag.svg/2000px-Red_flag.svg.png" >Add Red
  </button>
</span>

<span>
  <img src="http://epochmod.com/forum/uploads/monthly_2015_09/2000px-Solid_blue.svg.png.09e2d6f1de3f9a9192388a1737c19280.png" width="50" height="50" />
  <button type="button" class="addToFavorites" color="blue" img="http://epochmod.com/forum/uploads/monthly_2015_09/2000px-Solid_blue.svg.png.09e2d6f1de3f9a9192388a1737c19280.png" >Add Blue 
  </button>
</span>
<span>
 <img src="http://greensportsalliance.org/images/darkGreenSquare.gif" width="50" height="50" />
  <button type="button" class="addToFavorites" color="green" img="http://greensportsalliance.org/images/darkGreenSquare.gif" >Add Green
  </button>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what would suggest if I use figure tags around the image? When I try to use figure tags in disrupts the content flow

Comment: style your figure tags like " figure {   display:inline-block; width:whatever;
  height:whatever;  margin:auto;} " ..should work..

Comment: kindly tick answer as solve if this actually solve the issue...D

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you added an `img` property to your button:

```
<button type="button" class="addToFavorites" color="blue" img="http://epochmod.com/forum/uploads/monthly_2015_09/2000px-Solid_blue.svg.png.09e2d6f1de3f9a9192388a1737c19280.png">
```

You could use a data attribute instead, as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Your code would look like this:

```
<button type="button" class="addToFavorites" color="blue" data-img="http://epochmod.com/forum/uploads/monthly_2015_09/2000px-Solid_blue.svg.png.09e2d6f1de3f9a9192388a1737c19280.png">
```

And you would be able to access it like this:

```
yourButton = document.getElementsByClassName("addToFavorites");
imageDataAttribute = yourButton.dataset.img;
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I will take a look and give it a try. I'm still pretty new to jQuery so when using the yourButton JS do I need to include this in my 'shuffle' function or separate?

Comment: No, I just limited to answer how you would add the image url property to your button and how you would access it. You will have to add it to your shuffle code.